# Trouble Installing Numpy and Scipy

Tags: numpy

I'm running into difficulty what I run `python setup.py install` in the numpy directory.  It seems to be running alright, until it gets to a folder where permission is denied.  The error it throws is `copying build/scripts.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/f2py -> /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/f2py: Permission denied`.  If someone could please help me I'd like to get his up an running.  Thanks

Environment:  GCC: `i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)`
fortran: `GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.2.3`
And here is a gist of the output of what happens when I run `python setup.py build` https://gist.github.com/756792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the installer needs to add a script to `/usr/local/bin`, and your account doesn't have a permission to do so. You need to run it with elevated privileges: `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: What if you don't have access to an administrator account? Is there really no way to install f2py with user level privileges?

Comment: Try running `python setup.py install --help` and see if there is an option to install scripts only for current user; usually there is the `--install-scripts` option. As a last resort, you can edit the installation script inside the archive (be sure you know what you're doing).

Answer (score 3):

If you type in `sudo easy_install numpy` that solves the same problem that I have encountered.  This may have occurred due to using an Apple Mac which have already installed `easy_install` in your `/usr/bin`.  Typing `sudo easy_install numpy` if the package tries installing a script